# Webmethod problemas al generar información desde el serverside

Tags: javascript, c#, asp

Trabajo con ASP.NET, Bootstrap, Javascript y webmethods para obtener informacion del servidor parcialmente sin necesidad de un postback.

Mi problema es que al compilar la 2da función webmethod, la compilación del visual studio se vuelve imprevista: hace saltos aleatorios dentro de la función lo cual me parece que estoy haciendo algo mal.

tengo 3 funciones javascript, actualmente solo 2 están habilitadas, y de éstas 2, solo 1 función me responde adecuadamente.

Para que entiendan mi proyecto brevemente: si hago click en los botones con clase: btnRuta (id: btnRuta1, btnRuta2, btnRuta3) el evento click button me lleva a un funcion la cual copia el nombre del boton y lo lleva a ASP.NET a través del webmethod, y ejecuta un método el cual verifica el nombre del boton y en base al nombre atribuye los parametros especificos para que la consulta se ejecute y me retorne en una variable de tipo array y me pase los datos al javascript, y éste me reescriba los labels del html con la info que yo quiero.

El proyecto tiene 4 secciones, no todas ejecutan éste método, solo 3 de ellas.

La seccion A (grupo de botones btncheck), me funciona sin ningun problema, la seccion B me da problemas y la seccion C (botones clientes) ni si quiera está en planes.

Como dije anteriormente no estoy seguro si el webmethod y su declaración tengan que ver directamente con este error.

Dejo mi código y espero nos entendamos mutuamente.

```
           <div class="table-responsive">          
          <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
            <thead>
                                        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <button id="btnRuta1" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btnRuta btn-primary btn-block" onclick="RouteEvent()">
                        <span>CANAL DETALLE</span>
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                      <tr>   
             <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
             </tr>


                <tr>
                <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbDetalleCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbDetalleEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>       
              <tr>       
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbDetalleCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbDetalleEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>       
            </tbody>
          </table>  
          </div>

                                                <div class="table-responsive">          
          <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
            <thead>
                                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <button id="btnRuta2" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btnRuta btn-primary btn-block" onclick="RouteEvent()">
                        <span>CANAL MAYORISTA</span>
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  <tr>

             <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
             </tr>


                       <tr>
                <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbMayorCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbMayorEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>       
              <tr>

                 <td><asp:Label ID="lbMayorCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbMayorEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>


            </tbody>
          </table>  
          </div>

                                                <div class="table-responsive">          
          <table class="table" style="font-size:130%; font-family:Tahoma;">
            <thead>
                        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <button id="btnRuta3" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btnRuta btn-primary btn-block" onclick="RouteEvent()">
                        <span>CANAL SUPERMERCADO</span>
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

                      <tr>

             <th class="text-right thAzul" colspan="3">Evolución</th>
             </tr>
                       <tr>
                <td class="thAzul" rowspan=2>Cj. Vendidas</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbSuperCanal" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbSuperEvo" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>       
              <tr>

                <td><asp:Label ID="lbSuperCanal_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbSuperEvo_p" runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label></td>
               </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>  
          </div>
```

Mi Jquery (cabe mencionar que para llenar la seccion rutas ocupo usercontrol y los ids que en listo al final son los del after load en el html, ellos cargan a veces), el ChannelEvent me funciona bien, el RouteEvent me da problemas en el ASP, su funcion en jquery me la hace bien:

```
      $('.btn').click(function () {
                     var $boton = $(this);
                     if ($boton.hasClass('btnCheck')) {
                         ChannelEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                     }
                     if ($boton.hasClass('btnRuta')) {
                         RouteEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                     }
                     //if ($boton.hasClass('btnCliente')) {
                     //    ClienteEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                     //}
                 });



             });

             function ChannelEvent(buttonName) {


                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "inicio.aspx/CanalFunc",

                     data: '{name: "' + buttonName + '"}',
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: OnSuccess,
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);
                     }
                 });
             }
             function OnSuccess(response) {

                 document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[0];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[1];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[2];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[3];

                document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[4];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[5];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[6];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbMayorEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[7];

                document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperCanal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[8];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[9];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperCanal_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[10];
                document.getElementById('<%=lbSuperEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[11];

            }




            function RouteEvent(buttonRuta) {


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inicio.aspx/RutaFunc",

                    data: '{name: "' + buttonRuta + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess2,
                    failure: function (responseR) {
                        alert(responseR.d);
                    }
                });
            }
            function OnSuccess2(responseR) {
                document.getElementById('ruta1_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[0];
                document.getElementById('ruta1_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[1];
                document.getElementById('ruta1_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[2];
                document.getElementById('ruta1_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[3];
                document.getElementById('ruta1_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[4];
                document.getElementById('ruta2_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[5];
                document.getElementById('ruta2_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[6];
                document.getElementById('ruta2_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[7];
                document.getElementById('ruta2_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[8];
                document.getElementById('ruta2_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[9];
                document.getElementById('ruta3_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[10];
                document.getElementById('ruta3_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[11];
                document.getElementById('ruta3_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[12];
                document.getElementById('ruta3_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[13];
                document.getElementById('ruta3_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[14];
                document.getElementById('ruta4_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[15];
                document.getElementById('ruta4_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[16];
                document.getElementById('ruta4_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[17];
                document.getElementById('ruta4_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[18];
                document.getElementById('ruta4_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[19];
                document.getElementById('ruta5_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[20];
                document.getElementById('ruta5_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[21];
                document.getElementById('ruta5_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[22];
                document.getElementById('ruta5_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[23];
                document.getElementById('ruta5_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[24];
                document.getElementById('ruta6_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[25];
                document.getElementById('ruta6_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[26];
                document.getElementById('ruta6_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[27];
                document.getElementById('ruta6_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[28];
                document.getElementById('ruta6_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[29];
                document.getElementById('ruta7_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[30];
                document.getElementById('ruta7_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[31];
                document.getElementById('ruta7_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[32];
                document.getElementById('ruta7_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[33];
                document.getElementById('ruta7_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[34];
                document.getElementById('ruta8_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[35];
                document.getElementById('ruta8_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[36];
                document.getElementById('ruta8_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[37];
                document.getElementById('ruta8_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[38];
                document.getElementById('ruta8_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[39];
                document.getElementById('ruta9_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[40];
                document.getElementById('ruta9_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[41];
                document.getElementById('ruta9_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[42];
                document.getElementById('ruta9_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[43];
                document.getElementById('ruta9_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[44];
                document.getElementById('ruta10_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[45];
                document.getElementById('ruta10_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[46];
                document.getElementById('ruta10_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[47];
                document.getElementById('ruta10_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[48];
                document.getElementById('ruta10_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[49];
                document.getElementById('ruta11_lbRuta').innerHTML = responseR.d[50];
                document.getElementById('ruta11_lbQvta').innerHTML = responseR.d[51];
                document.getElementById('ruta11_lbQvtaEvo').innerHTML = responseR.d[52];
                document.getElementById('ruta11_lbQvta_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[53];
                document.getElementById('ruta11_lbQvtaEvo_p').innerHTML = responseR.d[54];

            }
```

Por último , el ASP C#

(declaro 2 veces webmethod libreria para cada función):

```
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static Array CanalFunc(string name)
    {


       // int i = 0;
        //string j = "";




        //session


        #region condicionales, nombre de botones
        if (name == "table1_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 1;
            spid = "PT-001.";
        }
        if (name == "table2_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 2;
            spid = "PT-003.";
        }
        if (name == "table3_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 3;
            spid = "PT-004.";
        }
        if (name == "table4_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 4;
            spid = "PT-002.";
        }
        if (name == "table5_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 5;
            spid = "PT-023.";
        }
        if (name == "table6_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 6;
            spid = "PT-006.";
        }
        if (name == "table7_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 7;
            spid = "PT-007.";
        }
        if (name == "table8_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 8;
            spid = "PT-008.";
        }
        if (name == "table9_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 9;
            spid = "PT-009.";
        }
        if (name == "table10_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 10;
            spid = "PT-010.";
        }
        if (name == "table12_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 12;
            spid = "PT-017.";
        }
        if (name == "table13_btnCheck")
        {
            pid = 15;
            spid = "PT-015";
        }

        #endregion

        if (!(pid==0))
         {


             Query.Sale.Instance.year = Query.Finance.Instance.year = Ano;
             Query.Sale.Instance.month = Query.Finance.Instance.month = Mes;
             Query.Sale.Instance.day = Query.Finance.Instance.day = dia;

             //string vmchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "SHALER", user, password);
             //VM = new VMDataContext(vmchain);


             //string dbrecordchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "DB_Record", user, password);
             //DBRECORD = new DBRECORDDataContext(dbrecordchain);

             Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleChannelProduct = Query.Sale.LevelTwo.UnionOrderSaleChannelProduct(pid, spid);

             #region Canales

             ListCanalA = (from x in Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleChannelProduct.Where(p => p.Year == Ano)
                           select new Query.Sale.Instance.ObjectListSale
                           {
                               Year = x.Year,
                               Channelidsec = x.Channelidsec,
                               Channelshortname = x.Channelshortname,                                   
                               Qtysold = x.Qtysold,
                           }).ToList();
             ListCanalB = (from x in Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleChannelProduct.Where(p => p.Year == Ano - 1)
                           select new Query.Sale.Instance.ObjectListSale
                           {
                               Year = x.Year,
                               Channelidsec = x.Channelidsec,
                               Channelshortname = x.Channelshortname,
                               Qtysold = x.Qtysold,
                           }).ToList();
             #endregion



             decimal d0, d1, d2, d3, m0, m1, m2, m3, s0, s1, s2, s3;
             decimal k; //Variable de ayuda para cálculos, se sobre escribe en ella.

             //Cajas vendidas en el canal 1 (Detalle)
             d0 = ListCanalA.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 1).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             k = ListCanalB.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 1).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             d1 = d0 - k;

             if (k == 0)
             {
                 d3 = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 d3 = d1 / k;
             }


             //Cajas vendidas en el canal 2 (Mayoristas)
             m0 = ListCanalA.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 2).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             k = ListCanalB.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 2).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             m1 = m0 - k;
             if (k == 0)
             {
                 m3 = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 m3 = m1 / k;
             }


             //Cajas vendidas en el canal 3 (Supermercados)
             s0 = ListCanalA.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 3).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             k = ListCanalB.Where(x =>  x.Channelidsec == 3).Sum(x => x.Qtysold);
             s1 = s0 - k;

             if (k == 0)
             {
                 s3 = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 s3 = s1 / k;
             }

             k = ListCanalA.Sum(x => x.Qtysold);



             if (k == 0)
             {
                 d2 = 0;
                 m2 = 0;
                 s2 = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 d2 = d0 / k;
                 m2 = m0 / k;
                 s2 = s0 / k;

             }



             //lbDetalleCanal   0
             //lbDetalleEvo     1
             //lbDetalleCanal_p 2
             //lbDetalleEvo_p   3

             //lbMayorCanal     4
             //lbMayorEvo       5
             //lbMayorCanal_p   6
             //lbMayorEvo_p     7

             //lbSuperCanal     8
             //lbSuperEvo       9
             //lbSuperCanal_p   10
             //lbSuperEvo_p    11

             canal_array[0] = d0.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[1] = d1.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[2] = d2.ToString("P2");
             canal_array[3] = d3.ToString("P2");

             canal_array[4] = m0.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[5] = m1.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[6] = m2.ToString("P2");
             canal_array[7] = m3.ToString("P2");

             canal_array[8] = s0.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[9] = s1.ToString("N2");
             canal_array[10] = s2.ToString("P2");
             canal_array[11] = s3.ToString("P2");                 

         }

        return canal_array;

     }


     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
     public static Array RutaFunc(string name)
     {
         int b = 0; //Contador individual para la variable array
         int i = pid; 
         string j = spid;
         string n;
         decimal r_0, r_1, r_2, r_3;
         decimal k; //Variable de ayuda para cálculos, se sobre escribe en ella.



         if (name == "btnRuta1")
         {
             rid = 1;

         }
         if (name == "btnRuta2")
         {
             rid = 2;

         }
         if (name == "btnRuta3")
         {
             rid = 3;

         }

         if (pid > 0) //Means the system expects channels get loaded first.
         {
             Query.Sale.Instance.year = Query.Finance.Instance.year = Ano;
             Query.Sale.Instance.month = Query.Finance.Instance.month = Mes;
             Query.Sale.Instance.day = Query.Finance.Instance.day = dia;

             string vmchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "SHALER", user, password);
             VM = new VMDataContext(vmchain);

             string vfinchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "VFIN", user, password);
             VFIN = new VFINDataContext(vfinchain);

             string dbrecordchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "DB_Record", user, password);
             DBRECORD = new DBRECORDDataContext(dbrecordchain);

             string rmchain = string.Format(stringconnection, datasource, "RM_Debug", user, password);
             RM = new RMDataContext(rmchain);


             //Query.Sale.Instance.VM = Query.Finance.Instance.VM = VM;
             //Query.Sale.Instance.VFIN = Query.Finance.Instance.VFIN = VFIN;
             //Query.Sale.Instance.DBRECORD = Query.Finance.Instance.DBRECORD = DBRECORD;
             //Query.Sale.Instance.RM = RM;

             Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleProductChannelRoute = Query.Sale.LevelTwo.UnionOrderProductChannelRoute(pid, spid, rid);

             #region Rutas


             ListRouteA = (from z in Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleProductChannelRoute.Where(p => p.Year == Ano)
                           select new Query.Sale.Instance.ObjectListSale
                           {
                               Year = z.Year,
                               Routename = z.Routename,
                               Routeid = z.Routeid,
                               Qtysold = z.Qtysold,
                           }).ToList();
             ListRouteB = (from z in Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleProductChannelRoute.Where(p => p.Year == Ano - 1)
                           select new Query.Sale.Instance.ObjectListSale
                           {
                               Year = z.Year,
                               Routename = z.Routename,
                               Routeid = z.Routeid,
                               Qtysold = z.Qtysold,
                           }).ToList();
             #endregion






             #region rutas
             //Cajas vendidas en cada canal, ciclo.

             for (int m = 1; m <= 11; m++)
             {
                 //n = ListRouteA.Where(z => z.Routeid == m).GroupBy(z => new { z.Routename }).Select(z => new { R = z.Key.Routename }).First().ToString();
                 n = "R" + m;
                 r_0 = ListRouteA.Where(z => z.Routeid == m).Sum(z => z.Qtysold);
                 k = ListRouteB.Where(z => z.Routeid == m).Sum(z => z.Qtysold);
                 r_1 = r_0 - k;
                 if (k == 0)
                 {
                     r_3 = 0;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     r_3 = r_1 / k;
                 }

                 k = ListRouteA.Sum(z => z.Qtysold);
                 if (k == 0)
                 {
                     r_2 = 0;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     r_2 = r_0 / k;

                 }
                 if (b == 0)
                 {
                     ruta_array[b] = n;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     b++;
                     ruta_array[b] = n;
                 }
                 b++;
                 ruta_array[b] = r_0.ToString("N2");
                 b++;
                 ruta_array[b] = r_1.ToString("N2");
                 b++;
                 ruta_array[b] = r_2.ToString("P2");
                 b++;
                 ruta_array[b] = r_3.ToString("P2");
             }

             #endregion

         }
         return ruta_array;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es complicado reproducir tu escenario sin el código completo pero sí que hay un error claro en el código javascript. Al asignar la función al evento click de los botones te sobra el último corchete y paréntesis:

```
  $('.btn').click(function () {
                 var $boton = $(this);
                 if ($boton.hasClass('btnCheck')) {
                     ChannelEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                 }
                 if ($boton.hasClass('btnRuta')) {
                     RouteEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                 }
                 //if ($boton.hasClass('btnCliente')) {
                 //    ClienteEvent($boton.attr('id'));
                 //}
             });



         }); // Esta línea sobra
```